# Using tc tbf on veth to limit ingress bandwidth works, but I don't know the detail

Tags: networking, docker, network-traffic

I found the Docker container's veth on the host, and used the following command to limit the ingress bandwidth of the container.

```
tc qdisc add dev veth root tbf rate 200mbit latency 50ms burst 800000
```

It works. However, I have another container, both of them are having heavy ingress traffic. My NIC's capacity is 1000m. As I understand, the ingress traffic goes to docker0 bridge first, and then goes into veth then leaves through the peer inside the container(net namespace).

I assume there will be two 500mbps go through each veths(which is the case when not using tc), one of them shrinks to 200mbit due to tbf. I tested it to validate my assumption, but there is one 800mbps traffic and one 200 mbps traffic. I thought the tbf only works after the traffic hits the veth, but apparently I'm wrong. Which part leads to this result?