# How to limit egress traffic of a docker network with `tc tbf`

Tags: networking, docker, network-traffic

I would like to limit the egress bandwidth of a docker network to 1Mbps. The bridge interface is `docker0`. I am using `tc tbf`:

```
tc qdisc add dev docker0 root handle 1: tbf rate 1000 kbit minburst 1000 burst 10000 limit 30000
```

The command does not have any effect on the `docker0` interface, whereas it perfectly works if it is applied on Docker container's `veth` on the host (as already reported by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369626/using-tc-tbf-on-veth-to-limit-ingress-bandwidth-works-but-i-dont-know-the-deta)).

I don't understand what the difference between `veth` and  `docker0` is.
Moreover, I believe that it is not a routing problem since the container egress traffic has to go first to the `veth` interface and then through the Docker bridge interface `docker0` accordingly to this picture:

[image: docker network example]

Thanks.

Comment: are you aware of https://github.com/shivacherukuri/Docker-Network-Bandwidth ?

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of this project. It seems that it uses `tc htc` under the hood. Unfortunately, I need to use `tc tbf` because I need also to limit the link queue size, not just the bandwidth.